# Getting NullReferenceException when trying to add a value to an array

Tags: c#, variables, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, nullreferenceexception

I'm having issues with this code.
Everytime when it runs, it returns me the 'System.NullReferenceException'.

```
// Clear out the Array of code words
wordBuffer = null;
Int32 syntaxCount = 0;

// Create the regular expression object to match against the string
Regex defaultRegex = new Regex(@"\w+|[^A-Za-z0-9_ \f\t\v]",
RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
Match wordMatch;

// Loop through the string and continue to record
// words and symbols and their corresponding positions and lengths
for (wordMatch = defaultRegex.Match(s); wordMatch.Success; wordMatch = wordMatch.NextMatch())
{
    var word = new Object[3] { wordMatch.Value, wordMatch.Index, wordMatch.Length };
    wordBuffer[syntaxCount] = word;
    Debug.WriteLine("Found = " + word[0]);
    syntaxCount++;
}

// return the number of symbols and words
return syntaxCount;
```

The exception occurs on those lines:

```
Debug.WriteLine("Found = " + word[0]);
                syntaxCount++;
```

Specifically when trying to get the `word[0]` value, and on the second line with the `syntaxCount`, but none of those values are null, as you can see in the image below:

[image]
The variable "s" is just a line of a RichEditBox, word[0] has a value, so why is it returning the NullReferenceException? syntaxCount has a value too :/

Comment: `wordBuffer = null;`. I'm not sure why you see error on next line, but exception should happen (as described in duplicate) on previous `wordBuffer[syntaxCount] = word;` line.

Comment: Side note: thanks for effort put in the question - it is nice to see amount of information you've collected/presented.

Comment: I don't think this is a dupilcate, as the OP does not now how arrays are working. This is not only about NullRef Exp.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Arrays are explicitly covered in [What is nullRef](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) too... Consider to update question to match your answer when you are done.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I know how dificult it is to understand incomplete codes, so I try to make it easier adding how much info I can. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the exception on the line `wordBuffer[syntaxCount] = word;`

You are using the wrong approach for storing the results. Arrays are not created automatically and they do not grow automatically. I.e., you need to define their size in advance with `string[] arr = new string[size]`. Use a list instead, as you do not know the size in advance here. Lists grow automatically:

```
// Initialize with
var wordBuffer = new List<string>();

// ...
// And then add a word to the list with
wordBuffer.Add(word);
```

You query the number of entries with `wordBuffer.Count` and you can access the items as in an array, once they have been added: `wordBuffer[i]`, where the index goes from `0` to `wordBuffer.Count - 1`. This makes the variable `syntaxCount` superfluous.

And of course, you can loop through a list with `foreach`.

Comment: Thanks, somehow I completely forgot about `List<T>`, this will make the code cleaner and easier to work.